# Temperature controlled urn on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, cooking-bishul, electricity

What issues may be at play when adjusting the temperature of an urn on Shabbat, e.g. from 200° F to 80° F, specifically on an urn pictured below*? (Assuming the water is already pre-boiled before Shabbat and no lights will turn on when temperature is adjusted. Would also appreciate technical input; it greatly helps in determining halachic outcome.)

[image: temperature controlled urn]

*One company I am aware of that makes this model is Magic Mill.

Comment: at the least tape the temperature knob so it cannot be adjusted by accident on Shabbos.

Comment: @sabba what would be wrong with accidentally adjusting it (is the OP's question)

Comment: Another point that applies to Yom Tov would be if it is a continuous rheostat or a *click type* (on off) type of controller.

Comment: Many of these types of urns have a built-in thermostat. In some cases, the unit turns on when it senses that the water temp. is too cold and it actually boils the water. I've heard the urn doing this, and seen the steam coming out the top of the urn. I can't say if this specific urn is prone to do this, so you need to check.

Comment: "Would also appreciate technical input". I think most of the responsibility is on you to find this out. For one thing, we don't even know which brand urn this is, so providing at least this info will focus your question better.

Comment: @DanF I see. Although wouldn't this then be the same halachic issue(s) as any other urn? By manually changing the temperature on Shabbat it would still only be a gerama just as emptying water from a standard urn and causing the heating mechanism to reboil.

Comment: Yes, it would be the problem with any urn, AFAIK. Many of these types of urns act this way. Some don't. Which is why you'll need to find out how your specific urn works.